# splitting string into an array unless comma between speech marks

Tags: php, csv, import

I'm writing a csv file important script. There are two separators that can be selected, comma or semi colon. I've noticed though that in the text file there are semi colons and commas in the middle of some of the text.  Each text field has speech marks around it but some of the fields are blank and some are numeric. I'm looking for a way to only split text that's outside the speech marks while leaving text instead the speech marks intact.

Here is the current function I'm using to split up the row.

```
function parse_lines($p_CSVLines,$c_Names,$separator)
{
    $content = FALSE;
    if( !is_array($content) ) { // the first line contains fields numbers
        $this->fields = $c_Names;
        $content = array();
    }

    foreach($p_CSVLines as $line_num => $line){
        if($line != ''){ // skip empty lines
            $elements = split($separator, $line);
            $item = array();
            foreach($this->fields as $id => $field){
                if( isset($elements[$id]) ){
                   $field = trim($field,"\"");
                   $item[$field] = trim($elements[$id],"\"");
                }
            }
            $content[] = $item;
        }
    }
    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Don't know if you considered using PHP's built in `fgetcsv` (See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) - it does what you want to do "by hand" very nicely

Comment: Or str_getcsv() - http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php - if your csv row isn't from a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that the use of `split()` is highly discouraged, it's now deprecated. You could use `preg_split()` or `explode()`.

What you want to do here is to use REGEX to search for the semi-colons and commas that aren't in the middle of the your text. `preg_split()` should get the job done with the right expression.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php